# -bash: phpize: command not found on Centos 6

Tags: php, centos

When I try to run `phpize` I get

```
-bash: phpize: command not found
```

I have run `yum -y install php-devel` but that returns:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.softaculous.com
 * extras: centos.schlundtech.de
 * rpmforge: mirror1.hs-esslingen.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't the command `phpize5` instead of `phpize`

Answer (score 5):

When you're unsure where a particular executable resides, you can query you YUM installation like so, using `repoquery`:

```
$ repoquery -q --file */phpize
php-devel-0:5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
php-devel-0:5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
```

#### fastestmirror

Yum makes use of plugins to enhance it's features. One of these plugins is called [fastestmirror](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumUtils/Plugins/Fastestmirror). Sometimes this plugin can be the cause of slowness. The mirror sites that this plugin selects can sometimes not be the best ones to use all the time.

You can remove the preferred list of mirrors from this plugin by deleting this file:

```
$ sudo rm /var/cache/yum/timedhosts.txt
```

Often times the fastestmirror plugin can cause confusion because some mirror is lagging behind the rest of the mirrors or original site. I'll typically disable it temporarily just to get around the issue like so:

```
$ sudo yum --disableplugin=fastestmirror install php-devel

-or-

$ sudo yum --noplugins install php-devel
```